Change javascript date with a timezone
I'm using Vue and I have this vue2-date-range-picker
<date-range-picker ref="picker"
                                   :class="[dateHasChanges ? 'daterange-picker-highlighted' : '']"
                                   :opens="opens"
                                   :ranges="ranges"
                                   :always-show-calendars="true"
                                   :auto-apply="true"
                                   value-type="timestamp"
                                   data-testid="filter-form-date-range-picker"
                                   v-model="dateRange">
                  <template v-slot:input="picker" style="min-width: 350px;">
                    {{ getDateRangeInputLabel(picker) }}
                  </template>
                </date-range-picker>

I have added some custom ranges with moment:
ranges: {
        'All Time': [null, null],
        'Today': [moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').startOf('day').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'), moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').endOf('day').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')],
        'Yesterday': [window.moment().subtract(1, 'day')._d, window.moment().subtract(1, 'day')._d],
        'This Week': [window.moment().startOf('week')._d, window.moment().endOf('week')._d],
        'This Month': [window.moment().startOf('month')._d, window.moment().endOf('month')._d],
        'Last 7 Days': [window.moment().subtract(7, 'day')._d, window.moment()._d],
        'Last 300 Days': [window.moment().subtract(30, 'day')._d, window.moment()._d],
        'Last 3 Months': [window.moment().subtract(3, 'month')._d, window.moment()._d],
        'Custom Range': [window.moment().subtract(1, 'day')._d, window.moment()._d]
      },

The problem is the following, I need to set with moment a timezone with date and time but the component doens't allow string, just objects and when I parse with .toDate() my timezone change for my local timezone.
I need this:

moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').startOf('day').format('MM/DD/YYYY
HH:mm:ss')

and I try this too

moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').startOf('day').toDate()

It doesn't matter where you are, I want to take a custom timezone due to if I select today: I want to see 07/10/2024 00:00:00 - 07/10/2024 23:59:59

Try formatting and displaying this props attributeenter image description here

date-format,Add this props

don't put images with text in questions, answers or comments. Rather put the text itself in it, if necessary with your explanation.
